# how to set app theme from settings preferences added in app

Tags: java, android

I want to set my app theme using settings preferences i have created.
this are my codes.
Tell me how to code after this.
MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.settings){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

SettingsActivity.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        if (findViewById(R.id.idFrameLayout) != null){
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.idFrameLayout, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

SettingsFragment.java

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="General">
        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="System Default"
            android:dialogTitle="Select Theme"
            android:entries="@array/pref_theme_cat_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_theme_cat_values"
            android:key="key_theme"
            android:summary="%s"
            android:title="Theme" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="pref_theme_cat_values">
        <item>System Default</item>
        <item>Dark</item>
        <item>Light</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="pref_theme_cat_entries">
        <item>System Default</item>
        <item>Dark</item>
        <item>Light</item>
    </string-array>
```

menu.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"/>
```

and in activity_settings.xml

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/idFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Below are output images

preferences.xml

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check [this](https://dev.to/aurumtechie/implement-dark-night-mode-in-an-android-app-with-a-listpreference-toggle-2k5i) or [this](https://medium.com/swlh/androids-dark-mode-through-user-configurations-4df9d75b0db0) tutorials

Comment: One of the articles has java version as well if you scroll down. Anyway, here is [the link](https://github.com/Aurum1611/DarkModePreferenceTutorialJava)